# Не сравниваются переменные php

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, pdo

У меня есть таблица в бд , там одно поле token

На вход получаю токен и я должен сравнить его с токеном который лежит в бд.

Но сравнения почему то-нет, ответ от сервера следующий: Result of strcmp (asda , 1) is 1

```
$token = $_GET["token"];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT token FROM Tokens WHERE token =? LIMIT 1")->execute(array($token));

echo("Result of strcmp ($token , $stmt) is ");

echo(strcmp ($token, $stmt));

if($stmt == $token ){
```

Comment: Открываем **[ДОКУМЕНТАЦИЮ](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php)** и читаем `execute - Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки.` .......вернулся  `true`, тобишь `1`

Comment: Я бы сказал, что где-то потерялся `fetch()` или какой-нибудь `numRows()`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и как это исправить?)

Comment: @MartinezToni вам нужно значение из бд, а не результат операции execute. Как написано выше:  Вытягиваются значения через fetch

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хорошо, тогда если я напишу так if($stmt == 1){
}

Comment: @АлексейШиманский то все должно заработать, но не работает))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  почему если я сравниваю с 0, он не сравнивается?

Comment: @MartinezToni не работает - так говорят бухгалтерши админу.........надо говорить что именно не работает, что вы ожидаете и отображает ли какие либо ошибки (их отображение кстати надо включить), что прописано в скобках и после условия и т.д.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ошибка в самом запросе, мне нужно узнать,если такое значение в бд?

И он всегда говорит,что есть, хотя значения этого нет. как это исправить)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ау

Comment: @ArchDemon и куда это вставлять?

Comment: @ArchDemon и где он потерялся?

Comment: Прочитайте же документацию: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php и http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 1):

Strcmp возвращает отрицательное число, если str1 меньше, чем str2; положительное число, если str1 больше, чем str2, и 0 если строки равны.
Я бы переписал 
`$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT token FROM Tokens WHERE token =? LIMIT 1")->execute(array($token))` на классический манер работы с sql запросами,чтобы выявить ошибку и понять как исправить.